# Get channel's filesize limit

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

While most discord servers have an 8MB limit for files, some servers have a 50MB limit, and some even up to 100MB. Is it possible to detect this programmatically using the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Discord.js v13

The upload limit for guilds/servers is determined by their [`premiumTier`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=premiumTier) ('Server Boost Status' in the client). The limit is 100 MB if it is `TIER_3`, 50 MB if it is `TIER_2`, and 8 MB otherwise.

Here's an example of how to get the file upload limit:

```js
const defaultUploadLimit = 8

/**
 * Gets the upload limit for a guild in MB.
 * @param {Guild} guild
 * @returns number
 */
const getUploadLimitForGuild = guild => {
  switch (guild.premiumTier) {
    case 'TIER_3': return 100
    case 'TIER_2': return 50
    default: return defaultUploadLimit
  }
}

/**
 * Gets the upload limit for a channel in MB.
 * @param {Channel} channel
 * @returns number
 */
const getUploadLimitForChannel = channel =>
  channel.guild ? getUploadLimitForGuild(channel.guild) : defaultUploadLimit
```

### Discord.js v12

Same thing, but `guild.premiumTier` will be `3`, `2`, `1`, or `0` instead of strings.

```js
const getUploadLimitForGuild = guild => {
  switch (guild.premiumTier) {
    case 3: return 100
    case 2: return 50
    default: return defaultUploadLimit
  }
}
```